# Inject component into other component results in singleton

Tags: angular

Here is part of my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: " "
})
export class QuoteComponent {
    address: boolean[] = [false, false];

    constructor() { }
     ...
}


import { QuoteComponent } from "...";
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: "...",
})
export class Addresses1Component {
    constructor(private quote: QuoteComponent) { }
}


import { QuoteComponent } from "...";
    @Component({
        selector: '...',
        templateUrl: "...",
    })
    export class Addresses2Component {
        constructor(private quote: QuoteComponent) { }
    }
```

With the above code and **without defining providers** anywhere, `QuoteComponent` is a singleton and `Addresses1Component, Addresses2Component` have access to that. I would expect to behave like *services* and not to be a singleton since I did not define it somewhere inside `providers` array. Any good explanation for that?

Comment: You're injecting a component in your constructor. I'm curious why this even compiles. But since it did, I'd say the QuoteComponent is used as global variable and not as an angular component or service. But I'm just guessing here. Could you provide some explanation why you don't create a service?

Comment: This component (QuoteComponent) creates a form which spans among the other two addresses components. That's why I want to inject it, as to get its properties and values.

Answer (score 0):

Component are not expected to be injectable. Create a shared component that contains the form template using reactive Forms API.

If your QuoteComponent creates a form that should be available in other components (with form data), create a service that will have a variable myFormData of the type that mimics the properties of the form model. Also, create setter and getter: `set formData()` and `get formData()` in this service.  This service should be injected into QuoteComponent, Addresses1Component, and Addresses2Component.

When the form is created, invoke the setter on the service. In your adress components, invoke the getter and use the method setValue to populate the form with the data from the service, e.g.:

```
this.myFormModel.setValue(myService.formData);
```